# adding dependency breaks maven project

Tags: java, maven-2, hbase

When I add org.apache.hbase as a dependency to my project, it causes build failures with another dependency

> [ERROR] An error occurred during dependency resolution of the following artifact:
>
> com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.4
>
> Caused by: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar': Cannot find parent: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project for project: null:jersey-core:bundle:null for project null:jersey-core:bundle:null
>
> com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.4

I am sure these two have a common parent of some sort; how do I resolve this and more broadly, how can I check for this error in the future?

EDIT:

Another dependency uses jersey-core:1.7; is there a way I can use both versions ? Can I force the hbase artifact to use the newer (1.7) version ?

Comment: Are you sitting behind a proxy ? Are you using a repository manager ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe adding this mirror to the settings.xml (/etc/maven2) file get you ride of the problem:

```
<mirror>
    <id>glassfish-mirror</id>
    <name>glassfish mirror</name>
    <url>http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public-releases</url>
    <mirrorOf>glassfish-repository</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```